# Why can't I return my "cmds" variable in my code?

Tags: python

I want to create a command robot but I cant return cmds(variable). It always crashes not giving me anything. The output is just blank after I enter n in variable con. I've been working on the problem for the past 2 days. It's really annoying and I hope someone can help.

```
import time



print("Hi User! Pick a name for me!")
time.sleep(1)

name = input("Name for Bot: ")


g = print("Ooh", name + "!", "thats a cool name!")


print("What should I call you?")
time.sleep(1)

user_name = input("Your name: ")

g1 = print(user_name + "...", "cool name!")
time.sleep(1)


cmds = input("Say any command you would like :) - ")


def slap(cmds):          
        slap_p = input("Who do you want to slap: ")
        caption_for_slap = input("Caption for slapping: ")
        print("Loading...")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(caption_for_slap, "", ". You deserved it", slap_p)
        con = input("Would you like to continue y/n - ")
        def con_p(cmds, con):
            if con == "y":
                return slap()
            elif con == "n":
                return cmds
        con_p()
        

if cmds == "./slap":
    slap(cmds)

while True:
    if cmds == "br":
        break
                

def about_rb():
        if cmds == "./about_rb":
            print("I am a robot named", name + ".", "Thanks to", user_name, "for picking that name for me!")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("My age is 35 :)")

if cmds == "./about_rb":
        about_rb()

def question():
    if cmds == "do you like Siri or Cortana":
        print("I love all robots! I dont really have a preference for both ♥")
```

Comment: How can your `while True` loop ever end?

Comment: `slap` doesn't return anything. Perhaps `return con_p()`, but then as I've said, there are other problems.

Comment: @Peter Wood will try

Answer (score 0):

##### Part 1: arguments for function calls

When issuing `./slap` as a command, there are two problems in this part:

```
    con = input("Would you like to continue y/n - ")
    def con_p(cmds, con):
        if con == "y":
            return slap()
        elif con == "n":
            return cmds
    con_p()
```

In the final line of this block, the newly created function `con_p` is called, but without any of the arguments (`cmds`, `con`). Since there is no default value for them either, the script crashes.

To resolve this, we just need to provide the required arguments; change the last line to:

```
    con_p(cmds, con)
```

You might think that this is a bit unnecessary, as you've already used those names in the line `def con_p(cmds, con):`, but that's just what the provided arguments will be known as *inside* the function `con_p()`, not where they're pulled from.

The second problem occurs when `con_p()` is called with `con = "y"`: then `con_p()` calls `slap()` again without arguments. We need to replace `return slap()` with `return slap(cmds)`.

**Side note**: I don't know if there is any further intent with the code block I copy/pasted above, but as is, the con_p() function can be removed. The entire block can be replaced with:

```
    con = input("Would you like to continue y/n - ")
    
    if con == "y":
        return slap(cmds)
```

`cmds` also isn't used inside `slap()`, so we can also just define it as `def slap():` instead of `def slap(cmds):`.

##### Part 2: infinite loop

As the code is executed from the first line to the last, the following block of code will always keep looping unless `cmds` equals `br`.

```
while True:
    if cmds == "br":
        break
```

Since we cannot adjust `cmds` *during* the loop, and it is asked only once, we have three scenarios based on the value of `cmds`:

1. `./slap` so we can slap people, and after we quit slapping (`con == "n"`) we will get in the infinite loop
2. `br` so we don't get caught in the loop, no other commands are executed, and the program exits without doing anything
3. any other value for `cmds` which doesn't get evaluated since we just end up in the loop forever.

I don't know for sure the intended purpose of this loop, but I think you want to put a loop around the entire code that asks for a command input and executes them, as such:

```
def slap(cmds):
    [...]
    

def about_rb():
    [...]
    

while True:
    
    cmds = input("Say any command you would like :) - ")

    if cmds == "./slap":
        slap(cmds)
        
    if cmds == "./about_rb":
        about_rb()

    if cmds == "br":
        break
```

Here, we first define all our functions. Then in an endless loop we keep asking the user for a new command, and run that command. Only when the command is "br", we break the loop and the computer continues with the code after the loop (if there is any).

##### Putting it all together

```
# imports
import time


# define functions
def slap(cmds):          
        slap_p = input("Who do you want to slap: ")
        caption_for_slap = input("Caption for slapping: ")
        print("Loading...")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(caption_for_slap, "", ". You deserved it", slap_p)
        con = input("Would you like to continue y/n - ")
        
        if con == "y":
            return slap(cmds)
        
        
def about_rb():
        if cmds == "./about_rb":
            print("I am a robot named", name + ".", "Thanks to", user_name, "for picking that name for me!")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("My age is 35 :)")
        

# name the bot
print("Hi User! Pick a name for me!")
time.sleep(1)
name = input("Name for Bot: ")
g = print("Ooh", name + "!", "thats a cool name!")


# name the user
print("What should I call you?")
time.sleep(1)
user_name = input("Your name: ")
g1 = print(user_name + "...", "cool name!")
time.sleep(1)


# start main loop
while True:
    
    # get command
    cmds = input("Say any command you would like :) - ")

    if cmds == "br":
        break
    
    if cmds == "./slap":
        slap(cmds)
        
    if cmds == "./about_rb":
        about_rb()
        
    if cmds == "do you like Siri or Cortana":
        print("I love all robots! I dont really have a preference for both ♥")
```